# Rails is_a?(Scope)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I'd like to get params from a request, namely: `model` and `scope`

Then, I'd like to fetch:

```
 eval("#{params[:model]}.#{params[:scope]}")
```

But... if a `delete_all` is passed in scope, I'd be endangered... So I'd like to test whether or not the `scope` is really a scope.

Any method to perform that?
(I'm using Rails3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not really answers your question, but may still be useful if there is no way to determine if a method is a scope or not:

You can check the resulting SQL

```
eval("#{params[:model]}.#{params[:scope]}.to_sql")
```

and check for dangerous SQL calls (DELETE, TRUNCATE, UPDATE, INSERT).

EDIT :

You can also check that the scope you're calling on your model is defined in this model, and not in a parent class like ActiveRecord::Base.

```
model.method(scope.to_sym).owner == model
```

EDIT 2 :

You can also call the scope on an empty set of records, and check the class of the result. For a scope it's going to be ActiveRecord::Relation, but for a delete_all it's going to be Fixnum :

```
model.where('0').scope.class == ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Comment: Thanks, I hope there is something more 'Railsy'